# Trouble Getting Scraper to the Correct 2FA Type When Logging Into a Google Account

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-oauth, seleniumbase

For a project I'm doing, it requires the user to be logged into their Google Accounts for it to work properly. I can't...

- log in via a logged-in profile (this isn't happening on the user's device), and I can't
- have the user do it themselves (the program doesn't have a display while it's running and I can't figure out how to get it to have one for the life of me because of missing dependencies I can't install)

So I've been coding a scraper to manually get through Google's login authenticator using SeleniumBase (It's the only anti-bot I've used that can get through Google's User/Password bot detection). Because I don't want to ruin the user's security while using the program completely, I'm coding a way for users to self-authenticate by having my scraper act as an intermediary between Google and the user. This would work all and well if I could actually *get* to the user's desired 2FA type in the first place.

For some context, my bot gets stuck at the part of 2FA where you need to choose how you're going to verify your identity after logging in with your username/password, then pressing "Try Another Way":

[An Image of Google's 2-Factor-Authentication Selection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krYoI.png)

My main problem lies in the unfortunate fact that these apparently **aren't** buttons. Instead of trying to figure out what exactly they were, I decided to find them via text like so: (Note-- this is in SeleniumBase)

```py
if sb.is_element_clickable('div:contains("8-digit backup codes")'):
      print("Found 2-Factor-Authentication option for using a backup code!")
```

Its Selenium version: (Note: I never tried compiling this code)

```py
try:
    chrome_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:contains("8-digit backup codes")'))
)
    print("Found 2-Factor-Authentication option for using a backup code!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Couldn't find the backup code 2FA option!")
```

This returns as True (as it should), but when you go to click the element, it instead defaults to the "Use your phone or tablet to get a security code (even if it’s offline)." This goes for **every other type of login when attempted this way**. I have no clue as to how to fix this, as direct XPATHs aren't viable long-term (The variable names of every element are randomized). Any suggestions?

### Debugging Information

To help anyone interested in handing a helping hand, here is the page's source info so you don't have to reproduce this yourself. Just know that it's... long. So long that now I need to post it as a file eslewhere because it's too big to go anywhere else! Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SpcY7y7wr9H1zvCb8fRZjW2sgX2Ibgyo/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for reading, and hopefully, you can find a solution! Let me know if you have any questions :)

### Code

Tbh it's probably easier to just run the code yourself, and with the benefit of hindsight, here it is:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from seleniumbase.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException as SeleniumTimeoutException

from seleniumbase import SB
import time

import os
import sys

gmail_overide = "Jediweirdo@gmail.com"
password_overide = os.environ["GOOGLE_PASSWORD"]
debug_screenshots_path = "Debug Screenshots"
activate_attempted_solutions = {
  "Using XPATHS (to text) instead of CSS Selectors": False
}
# Do not change this var unless you know what you're doing!
debug_folders = ["Login", "Errors", "Warnings"]

"""
Edit the values abover to your liking! Note that ONLY 1 solution in 
activate_attempted_solutions can be attempted while the program is 
running, and the program will still function if nothing is selected. 
Here's a quick summary what each solution attempt does to the code:

Normal Login (Runs if everything is False):
  Description:
    Uses "div:contains("Some text")" to find the selected 2fa 
    button. Simple, yet to the point.
  Result of Running:
    All but "Offline Code"'s 2fa button are found by the 
    program, but when the program clicks on them, it will always go 
    to the "Offline Code" 2fa page, no matter which option the user  
    chooses

Using XPATHS (to text) instead of CSS Selectors: 
  Description:
    Changes the code to use Full XPATHs obtained via the copy element 
    dropdown in Inspect Element instead of CSS Selectors. The XPATHS 
    lead directly to the <div> that contains the text describing the 
    2FA.
  Result of Running: (Semi-Fix)
    The program is only to finds the 8-digit Backup 
    Code and the Offline Device Code options, reguardless of if the
    user has the other 2FA options enabled on their account
-----
As a quick reminder, my problem is that I can't figure out how to 
click on the 2FA option the user selects when they use this program. 

For the sake of simplicity, the only function you have to edit to 
make this work is complete_tfa(), which should be located right 
below this multi-line comment. The rest only exists for the purposes 
of replroducing my problem without much work on your end. Good luck, 
and thanks for reading!
"""
def complete_tfa(driver): # tfa stands for "Two Factor Authentication"
  success_count = 0
  tfa_options = {
    "Tap Yes": "on your phone",
    "SMS Code (Recommended)": "verification code at", 
    "Authenticator": "verification code from",
    "Backup Code": "8-digit backup codes",
    "Offline Code": "even if it's offline"
  }
  tfa_options_text_xpath = {
    "Tap Yes": "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/text()[2]",
    "SMS Code (Recommended)": "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/text()", 
    "Authenticator": "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/text()[1]",
    "Backup Code": "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div/ul/li[5]/div/div[2]",
    "Offline Code": "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]"
  }
  try:
    driver.click(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='yDmH0d']/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/button/span")
  except NoSuchElementException:
    print("[WARNING] Couldn't find the 2FA Button! Expect either an error or for some 2FA attempts to be unaccessible from accidental overuse!")
    driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Warnings/TimeoutException - Try Another Way Button.png")
  else:
    driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/2FA Button.png")

  for tfa_type, query in tfa_options.copy().items():
    if activate_attempted_solutions["Using XPATHS (to text) instead of CSS Selectors"]:
      print(f"[XPATH] Checking for {tfa_type}...")
      found_tfa_option = driver.is_element_clickable(By.XPATH, tfa_options_text_xpath[tfa_type])
    else:
      print(f"Checking for {tfa_type}...")
      found_tfa_option = driver.is_element_clickable(f'div:contains("{query}")')
    
    if found_tfa_option:
      print(f"Found 2-Factor-Authentication Item {tfa_type}! Adding to the availiable pool...")
      success_count += 1
      tfa_option = f"{success_count}. {tfa_type}"
      tfa_options[tfa_option] = tfa_options.pop(tfa_type) # Modifies the current key to include a number for the user to select in the terminal
    else:
      print(f"[WARNING] Looks like you never set up for {tfa_type}!")
  # print(f"[INFO] {tfa_options}")

  # NOTES: 
  # - If it finds 1 Valid 2FA option, it will automatically select it.
  # - If there's more than 1 Valid 2FA option, it will prompt the user to select one via a while loop
  # - If there's no Valid 2FA options, the program commits die
  if success_count == 0:
    print("[ERROR] Couldn't find any 2FA types!")
    driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/TimeoutException - No 2FA.png")
    # driver.fail()
    return False
  elif success_count > 1:
    print("Choose your 2FA method:")
    for key in tfa_options.keys():
      if key[0].isdigit(): # If the 1st char in the key is a digit then it's a successful option
        print(key)  
    while True:
      tfa_choice = input("Enter the number corresponding to your choice here: ")
      if tfa_choice.strip().isdigit():
        if int(tfa_choice.strip()) <= success_count:
          tfa_choice = int(tfa_choice)
          break
      print("That's not a valid number! Go again:")
  else:
    print("You sorta only have one option, so we're gonna go with that...")

  # How the program will find the 2FA option the user selected and clicks on it
  for key in tfa_options.copy().keys():
    if key[0].isdigit():
      if int(key[0]) == tfa_choice:
        if activate_attempted_solutions["Using XPATHS (to text) instead of CSS Selectors"]:
          print(f"[XPATH] Attempting to click on {key}...")
          driver.click(By.XPATH, tfa_options_text_xpath[key[key.find('.') + 2:]]) # Getting rid of the numbers for compatibility with the xpath varient of tfa_options
        else:
          driver.click(f'div:contains("{tfa_options[key]}")')
        tfa_options[key] = True # Used as an identifier to redirect to the correct function
      tfa_options[key[key.find('.') + 2:]] = tfa_options.pop(key) # Gets rid of the number added for the user to select 
    print(f"{key[0]}")
  print(tfa_options)
  
  time.sleep(3) # So the program wait for Google to go to the next page before screenshotting
  
  # Redirects user to its corresponding function
  if isinstance(tfa_options["Tap Yes"], bool):
    return check_if_out_of_tfa(tap_yes_tfa(driver))
  elif isinstance(tfa_options["SMS Code (Recommended)"], bool):
    return check_if_out_of_tfa(sms_tfadriver(driver))
  elif isinstance(tfa_options["Authenticator"], bool):
    return check_if_out_of_tfa(authenticator_tfa(driver))
  elif isinstance(tfa_options["Backup Code"], bool):
    return check_if_out_of_tfa(backup_code_tfa(driver))
  elif isinstance(tfa_options["Offline Code"], bool):
    return check_if_out_of_tfa(offline_code_tfa(driver))
  else:
    print("[ERROR] How did you break this so badly?!")
    driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/StupidCoder - Invalid 2fa Choice.png")
    # driver.fail()
    return False
    

    
# These are all basically empty, so don't worry much about them
def tap_yes_tfa(driver):
  driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/2fa Chosen - Tap Yes")
  return login_check(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")
def sms_tfa(driver):
  driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/2fa Chosen - SMS Message")
  return login_check(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")
def authenticator_tfa(driver, max_attempts = 3):
  driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/2fa Chosen - Authenticator")
  return login_check(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")
def backup_code_tfa(driver):
  driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/2fa Chosen - Backup Code")
  return login_check(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")
def offline_code_tfa(driver):
  driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/2fa Chosen - Offline Code")
  return login_check(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")

def delete_old_debug_info():
  if not os.path.exists(debug_screenshots_path):
    print(f"The chosen Debug Screenshots Path ('{debug_screenshots_path}') doesn't exist on your PC! Did you change debug_screenshots_path?")
    exit()
  for folder in debug_folders:
    if not os.path.exists(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/{folder}"):
      print(f"Creating a screenshot debug folder stored at {debug_screenshots_path}/{folder}...")
      os.mkdir(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/{folder}")
  
  print("Deleting old news...")
  for folders in os.listdir(debug_screenshots_path):
    for files in os.listdir(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/{folders}"):
      os.remove(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/{folders}/{files}")

def login_via_password():
  delete_old_debug_info()
  print("Alright, let's get you logged in.")
  username = gmail_overide
  password = password_overide
  print("Creating the webdriver...")
  with SB(uc=True) as driver:
    driver.open("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login") # Getting to the login page
    print("Going to Google Login Page...")
  # Get rid of the cookies button in the way of the Google Button
    try:
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/SO Login Page.png")
      driver.click('//button[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]')
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/Cookieless SO Login Page.png")
    except NoSuchElementException:
      print("[WARNING] Couldn't Find Stuff in the Way!")
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Warnings/NoSuchElementException - Cookies.png")

    # Go to and click the Google login button
    try:
      driver.click('//*[@id="openid-buttons"]/button[1]')
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print("[ERROR] Element is not clickable because something is in the way!")

        return fail(str(error))
    else:
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/Google Email Login Page.png")
      print("Entering Your Credentials...")
    # Enters the email
    try:
      driver.type('//input[@id="identifierId"]', username)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("[ERROR] Could not find the username field!")
        driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/TimeoutException.png")
        # driver.fail()
        return False
    else:
        driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/Google Username Field.png")
    
    # Presses Next
    try:
      driver.click('button:contains("Next")') 
    except TimeoutException:
      print("[ERROR] Could not find the email submit button!")
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/TimeoutException.png")
      # driver.fail()
      return False
    else:
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/Google Password Field (Submitted Username).png")

    # Enters the password
    try:
      driver.type("input[type='password']", password)
    except (TimeoutException, ElementNotVisibleException)as e:
      if str(type(e).__name__) == "ElementNotVisibleException":
        print(f"[ERROR] '{gmail_overide}' is an Invalid Email! Did you change gmail_overide?")
        driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/ElementNotVisibleExeption - Bad email.png")
        # driver.fail()
        return False
      else:
        driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/TimeoutException - Busted.png")
        print(f"[ERROR] Could not find the password field! We probably got busted... Check in {debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/TimeoutException - Busted.png")
        # driver.fail()
      return False
      
    # Presses Next
    try:
      driver.click('button:contains("Next")')
    except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
      print("[ERROR] Couldn't find the password submit button!")
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/{type(e).__name__}.png")
      # driver.fail()
      return False
      
    # Checks if the account has 2FA
    logged_in = login_check(driver, "https://stackoverflow.com/")
    if logged_in == True: # Success! Got to SO
      print("Wow, I think we made it across the firewall! Maybe there's hope afterall...")
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/Got Past the Google Guards.png")
      # driver.fail()
      return True 
    elif logged_in == "Redirected": # Redirected to 2FA Page
      print("Login Successful, but it looks like you got 2FA enabled. We'll have to go through that manually!")
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Login/2FA Enabled.png")
      return complete_tfa(driver) # tfa stands for "Two Factor Authentication"
    else: # It denied the password and didn't go anywhere
      print(f"[ERROR] '{password_overide}' is a Bad Password! Did you change password_overide?")
      del username, password
      driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/TimeoutException - Bad Password.png")
      # driver.fail()
      return False

def login_check(driver, target_url):
  """
  What it does is simple-- it checks if the user is at the target URL or not. 
  Has 3 possible returns: 
  - True (got to target email)
  - False (Never changed pages)
  - "Redirected" (Redirected to a different page, but not the targeted one)
  """
  starting_url = driver.get_current_url()
  try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: target_url in driver.get_current_url())
    return True
  except SeleniumTimeoutException:
    if starting_url != driver.get_current_url():
      return "Redirected"
    else:
      return False

def check_if_out_of_tfa(logged_in):
  if logged_in == "Redirected":
    print("[ERROR] Wha..??? Where did it take you???")
    driver.save_screenshot(f"{debug_screenshots_path}/Errors/WrongWarpException - Post 2FA.png")
    drivr.fail()
    return False
  else:
    return logged_in

# RUNTIME CODE
print(f"---------------------------------------\nLogged in? {login_via_password()}")
```

**DO NOT WORRY ABOUT CHANGING MOST OF THE CODE HERE!!!** This is just the bare minimum needed to get to the part that I'm struggling with. The real problem lies in `complete_tfa()` when it goes to click on the 2FA you selected. It just clicks on the wrong thing entirely! Fill out the 3 variables on the top (gmail, password, and the path where you want debug information saved), then the program will do the rest itself

### Attempts made to solve the problem

I'll update this section as I try more things to get this to work. Anytime I update things here, I'll also update the provided code to mouse a snapshot for it. Check both! Anyway, here's what has been tried so far:

- Using full XPATHs instead of jQuery-like CSS Selectors

Comment: Google will detect this as a bot eventually.  It may not immediately, but somewhere along the line... probably before logging in completely, it will.  It may also have some effect on the user's account.  They'll think it's been hacked, so I'd be very careful with this.  There are probably various legitimate ways to do what you are trying to do using a Google API of some sort.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! This is just a personal project I'm doing for a science fair, so I'm not planning on sharing this with real users. As for using Google's YouTube API, I can't because its' credit system only allows 5 uploads before I can't use it to do anything. If I use Selenium, I can upload 50-100 videos/day and still use YouTube to do other things. My project is using YouTube for cloud storage, so it will involve a lot of interactions with YouTube that the API can't handle as it currently is. But, let me know if you have other ideas to log in than this, and I'll give it a shot!

Comment: You could always prompt the user to enter their login info/go through the 2nd step.  But again, Google's bot detection is pretty darn good, so that browser session would probably be detected pretty quick.

Comment: I'm a little confused. As the code is now, it already prompts the user for their login information, and I'm planning on doing the same for the 2-factor authentication. My problem is that I can't find the element that contains the link to the 2fa type that the user selected (my code keeps clicking on a different 2fa option). If you're saying to just let the user take over to log in, I also can't do that because I can't for the life of me figure out how to get Selenium/SeleniumBase to display the browser due to missing dependencies that I can't install (apt-get/install doesn't work with my "OS")

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning that before-- I'll edit my question is include that

Comment: sounds like you're launching with "headless" flag.  Don't set that so that the user can see the browser.

Comment: Man, I wish that was the issue... it would make my life a lot easier.  My code uses [SB Syntax #21](https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/syntax_formats/#sb_sf_21), which means I toggle headless mode by doing `with SB(uc=True, headless=False) as driver:` (at least to my knowledge). The uc argument works, but the headless does nothing. I've also tried `headed=True` to no avail. The full list of things you can pass to SB can be found [here](https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/customizing_test_runs/) and the (semi-useless) API doc is [here](https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/method_summary/)